# Using Areas, it doesn't seem to be able to figure out which controller I want

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm confused, I created an area named 'Admin' and I have these 2 controllers:

```
/admin/users/...
```

and

```
/users/..
```

Now if I try and link to this url:

```
/users/list
```

I get this error:

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'User'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a
```

'namespaces' parameter.

**I find it confusing why it doesn't work, can't it figure out that this UserController is the one that isn't in the Area?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When areas are introduced, there is the potential for ambiguity between identically named Controllers ref: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx

Try adding this in your Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  //all your other routes

  routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }, // Defaults
    new[]{"Your.NameSpace"}                       // Namespaces
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem by setting the namespace to your routes

like this sample below

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "My.Controllers" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "My.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: I don't need the admin definition, it works w/o it.

Comment: well in the future maybe you need it!so its better to have it in place!